# How to find the SQL Server logins for a domain user who have accessed db? (there are several sql logins by "windows user group")

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

There are several SQL Server logins which are created from Windows user group.

When a client connects to SQL Server via Windows authentication, how to confirm this client belongs to a Windows group?

thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't completely understand the question, are you asking how to tell if a login is a Windows login or a SQL login?

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer from the internet.

summary:   there is a user connect to database via windows authentication, and we can get it's corresponding "SQL Login Name / privilege" by this command: exec xp_logininfo 'domain\user'.

select system_user

---

domain1\whxu
(1 row(s) affected)

Exec xp_logininfo 'domain1\whxu'

account name       type    privilege  mapped login name       permission path
-----------------  -----   ---------  ------------------      ------------------------------------------------------------
domain1\whxu       user    admin       domain1\whxu           BUILTIN\Administrators
(1 row(s) affected)